# I need a sensible and simple Plone project directory structure

Tags: plone

I've been asked to build a website with Plone.  I would also like to use git version control for this project.  Ideally, I would have all the work I do stored in one directory -- my project directory -- which will also make version control simple.  Can anyone point me to a resource that explains how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We keep our company project skeleton at https://github.com/niteoweb/niteoweb.skel.plone.

It has some of our internal specifics, but should be usable. At least as a point of reference.

Comment: Thanks.  Also, I've noticed that as I add content to the site through the web interface, Plone modifies Data.fs, which I guess is the ZODB database.  Should this Data.fs file also be under version control, so that I can easily rollback changes I make through the web GUI?  I would like to be able to use Git to take snapshots of my site along the way as I develop.

Comment: @JonCrowell: The Data.fs file is indeed the object database. Use [`bin/repozo`](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/backup-plone) to create backups and store those; the `Data.fs` is going to be big..

Comment: Also, the tutorial.todoapp (http://tutorialtodoapp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) gives you pointers on building your first Plone app and can act as a project skeleton.